# How to update multiple rows of forms in MYSQL per button click?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am developing a php site to sort data for the exporting of terrestrial laser scanning data in a electrical design company.  When one row of data is present the forms update in MYSQL fine, but as soon as I display 2 or more rows of data the multiple rows conflict with each other when the submit but is click.

My aim is to individually sort through each row of data separately and update via MYSQL when I click submit on the row. But like I said, multiple rows conflict. Can I some how re-code it to specify data entered in forms only on a certain row?

the problem also stems from wanting to display current existing data in each cell through the forms so I know which is entered and what is not.

I apologize immensely for the untidy coding, and as you may judge I am very new to this. It's not my profession.

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {    

    echo "<tr>";
    echo '<td>' . $row->point_number . '&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="delete-final.php?id=' . $row->id . '">Delete</a></td>';
    echo "<td>" . $row->easting . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row->northing . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row->reduced_level . "</td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' name='description' value='$row->description'  size='2'/></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='number' name='string_number' value='$row->string_number'  size='1'/></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='number' name='pole_number' value='$row->pole_number'  size='1'/></td>";
    // drop down menu for poles size
    echo    '<td><select name="pole_length">';
    echo    '<option>' . $row->pole_length . '</option>';
    echo    '<option value=' . $pole30 . '>30&apos;</option>';
    echo    '<option value=' . $pole35 . '>35&apos;</option>';
    echo    '<option value=' . $pole11 . '>11</option>';
    echo    '<option value=' . $pole12 . '>12</option>';
    echo    '<option value=' . $pole40 . '>40&apos;</option>';
    echo    '<option value=' . $pole125 . '>12.5</option>';
    echo    '<option value=' . $pole13 . '>13</option>';
    echo    '<option value=' . $pole45 . '>45&apos;</option>';
    echo    '<option value=' . $pole14 . '>14</option>';
    echo    '<option value=' . $pole15 . '>15</option>';
    echo    '<option value=' . $pole155 . '>15.5</option>';
    echo    '<option value=' . $pole17 . '>17</option>';
    echo    '<option value=' . $pole185 . '>18.5</option>';
    echo    '<option value=' . $pole20 . '>20</option>';
    echo    '</select></td>';
    // echo '<td>' . $row[8] . '</td>';
    // drop down menu for Pole strength
    echo    '<td><a>' . $row->pole_strength . '&nbsp;</a><select name="pole_strength">';
    echo    '<option></option>';
    echo    '<option value=' . $poleA . '>A</option>';
    echo    '<option value=' . $poleB . '>B</option>';
    echo    '<option value=' . $pole5 . '>5</option>';
    echo    '<option value=' . $pole8 . '>8</option>';
    echo    '<option value=' . $pole12 . '>12</option>';
    echo    '<option value=' . $pole16 . '>16</option>';
    echo    '<option value=' . $pole20 . '>20</option>';
    echo    '</select></td>';

    //echo '<td>' . $row[9] . '</td>';
    // drop down menu for Pole Type

    echo    '<td><a>' . $row->pole_type . '&nbsp;</a><select name="pole_type">';
    echo    '<option></option>';
    echo    '<option value=' . $poleWOOD . '>Wood</option>';
    echo    '<option value=' . $poleCONC . '>Concrete</option>';
    echo    '<option value=' . $poleSTEEL . '>Steel</option>';
    echo    '<option value=' . $poleSTOBIE . '>Stobie</option>';
    echo    '<option value=' . $poleIBCONC . '>I-be...Conc</option>';
    echo    '<option value=' . $poleFABST . '>Fab Steel</option>';
    echo    '</select></td>';

    echo '<td>' . $row->pole_top. '</td>';

    echo "<td><input type='text' name='remark' value='$row->remark'/></td>";

    echo "<td>" . $row->circuitheight_1 . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row->circuitinsulatorleft_1 . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row->circuitremark_1 . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row->circuitheight_2 . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row->circuitinsulatorleft_2 . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row->circuitremark_2 . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row->circuitheight_3 . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row->circuitinsulatorleft_3 . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row->circuitremark_3 . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row->circuitheight_4 . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row->circuitinsulatorleft_4 . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row->circuitremark_4 . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row->circuitheight_5 . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row->circuitinsulatorleft_5 . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row->circuitremark_5 . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row->stayattachmentheight1 . "</td>";
    echo "<td><button type='submit' name='submit' value=' . $row->point_number . '/>SEND</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}   

echo "</table>";


if (isset($_POST['submit']))

    {   


        $point_no = $_POST['submit'];
        $point_number = substr($point_no, 2, 3);
        $description = htmlentities($_POST['description'], ENT_QUOTES);
        $string_number = htmlentities($_POST['string_number'], ENT_QUOTES);
        $pole_number = htmlentities($_POST['pole_number'], ENT_QUOTES);
        $pole_length = htmlentities($_POST['pole_length'], ENT_QUOTES);
        $pole_strength = htmlentities($_POST['pole_strength'], ENT_QUOTES);
        $pole_type = htmlentities($_POST['pole_type'], ENT_QUOTES);
        $remark = htmlentities($_POST['remark'], ENT_QUOTES);



        if ($description == '' || $string_number == '')
            {

                $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';

                //echo "<h2>" . $row->$point_number  .  $easting  . $northing . $reduced_level ."</h2>";
            }
        else
            {

                if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE final SET description = ?, string_number = ?, pole_number = ?, pole_length = ?, pole_strength = ?, pole_type = ?, remark = ? WHERE point_number=?"))
                    {
                        $stmt->bind_param("siissssi", $description, $string_number, $pole_number, $pole_length, $pole_strength, $pole_type, $remark, $point_number);
                        $stmt->execute();
                        $stmt->close();
                    }

                else
                    {
                        echo "ERROR: could not prepare SQL statement.";
                    }



            }
```

Comment: Oh god, those `echo`s. Use a [template](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/17/getting-started-with-php-templating/)

Comment: You need to make each row a separate form.

Comment: yeah i am just rushing it, lol, ill tidy it up one day

Comment: you could specify the html element names as array i.e name="pole_length[]",name="pole_type[]" etc. Now the browser sends all information and PHP parses it as an array. Hence in PHP you could use access it via index in a for loop or foreach. Just print_r($_POST) to see the result.